# Multiple List Plots for Arbitrary Set of Data

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

I'm trying to write some automated data analysis code for my research group, but I've run into a snag with Mathematica which I just can't seem to iron out.

We generate data of the form:

```
{{0,-2,-1,0,1,2...},
 {380,1,2,3,4,5...},
 {384,6,7,8,9,10...},
 .
 .
 .
}
```

Where, if the matrix is called data, `data[[1,2;;]]` is a selection of Voltage values, and `data[[2;;,1]]` is a selection of Wavelength values. `data[[2;;,2;;]]` gives Intensity.

I know that the wavelength values are defined by the instrument, but the voltage sweep is user-defined, so its dimensions are not fixed.

In MatLab, I would do the following:

```
a=size(data);
hold on
for i=2:a(2)
    plot(wavelength,data(2:end,i))
end
```

and this would generate my desired result of a single plot, with multiple traces each corresponding to a given measurement.

In Mathematica, I've tried several methods each without success. Because ListLinePlot expects a list of form {x1,y1},{x2,y2},... I figure there must be some obvious way to treat the data to achieve the desired result, but I haven't found it. If there were an equivalent `hold on` function in Mathematica, I would do the following:

```
HoldOn
Do[
ListLinePlot[{Wavelength,data[[2;;,t]]}//Transpose],
{t,2,Dimensions[data][[2]]}
]
```

But as far as I can find, such a function doesn't exist.

Is there some slick way I can do this that I'm missing?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you mean, then the following might work (note that I have added an extra line of fake data):

```
data = {
   {  0, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2},
   {380,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5},
   {384,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10},
   {386, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}};

ListLinePlot[
  Transpose@data[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]],
  DataRange -> MinMax@data[[2 ;;, 1]],
  PlotLabels -> data[[1, 2 ;;]]
]
```

[image: plots]

Here [`DataRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html)is the key element to the solution: it specifies what range of actual coordinates the data should be assumed to occupy, so you do not need to provide a list of ${x, y}$ coordinate pairs, but simply a list of $y$ coordinates, and then the abscissae are reconstructed for you.

This also makes no assumptions on the size of the data set; it simply expects the first column to contain wavelengths to set the `DataRange`; the first row is used as labels for each plot line.

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I was looking for!